# How can I fix error: class not found using Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to work on my model using Laravel.

Table name: refregions

Model: app/Refregion

Controller: in  one of my function I have this code:

`$regions = Refregion::all();`

And I defined the model on controller

`use app\Refregion;`

Can someone tell me why class cannot be found?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using the wrong path of Model in your controller.
you have to use the following one instant of this one 'use app\Refregion;'.

```
use App\Refregion;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Controller you have to use like this below

```
use App\Refregion;
```

Or

```
use \App\Refregion;
```

Comment: Why `\App` also a way?

Comment: @vivek_23 Yes. You can also use that way

Comment: `\App` would make it look into global namespace I presume `App` is autoloaded from composer. Since, we don't have any collisions, I think `App\Refregion` is fine.

Comment: @vivek_23 I agree with you. Even `use app\ Refregion;` also works.

Comment: Thanks A.A vivek I found it a while ago. Your solutions are right. Thanks  you